# ChartJS - Update doesn't work when I get data from an API to get new data

Tags: javascript, angular, chart.js

I have issue where when I update chart with new data, the data just append to a chart.

**.ts file**

```
export class InfoComponent implements OnInit {

  public chart: Chart = [];
  id: any;
  date = [];
  price = [];

  constructor(private cryptoAPIService: CryptoAPIService, private route: ActivatedRoute) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.id = this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('id');
    console.log(this.id);
    this.getValueById(1);
  }


  getValueById(period) {

    if (typeof this.chart.canvas !== "undefined") {
        console.log(this.date[0]);
        return this.cryptoAPIService.getChartValues(this.id, period).subscribe(res => {
        for(let val of res[0]) {
          var temp = new Date(val[0]).toLocaleTimeString('en', { year: 'numeric', month: 'short', day: 'numeric', hour12: false, hour: '2-digit', minute: '2-digit' });
          this.date.push(temp);
          val[1] = Math.round((val[1] + Number.EPSILON) * 100) / 100; // round to 2 decimals
          this.price.push(val[1]);
        }
        console.log("Chart created");
        console.log(this.date);

        this.chart.data.labels = this.date;
        this.chart.data.datasets[0].data = this.price;
        this.chart.update();
      });
    } else {
    return this.cryptoAPIService.getChartValues(this.id, period).subscribe(res => {
      for(let val of res[0]) {
        var temp = new Date(val[0]).toLocaleTimeString('en', { year: 'numeric', month: 'short', day: 'numeric', hour12: false, hour: '2-digit', minute: '2-digit' });
        this.date.push(temp);
        val[1] = Math.round((val[1] + Number.EPSILON) * 100) / 100; // round to 2 decimals
        this.price.push(val[1]);
      }
      this.chart = new Chart('canvas', {
        type: 'line',
        data: {
          labels: this.date,
          datasets: [
            {
              data: this.price,
              borderColor: '#45b6fe'
            },
          ]
        },
        options: {
          tooltips: {
            callbacks: {
              label: (tooltipItems, data) => {
                  return '$' + data.datasets[tooltipItems.datasetIndex].data[tooltipItems.index];
              }
          },
        },
          legend: {
            display: false
          },
          scales: {
            xAxes: [{
              display: true
            }],
            yAxes: [{
              ticks: {
                userCallback: function(tick) {
                  return '$' + tick.toString() ;
                }
              },
              display: true
            }],
          }
        }
      });
      console.log("Chart created");
    });
  }
}
}
```

**HTML file**

```
<a (click)="getValueById(1)">24h</a>
<a (click)="getValueById(7)">7 Days</a>
<a (click)="getValueById(30)">Month</a>
<a (click)="getValueById(365)">Year</a>

<div id="chartDiv" class="chart" *ngIf="chart">
  <canvas id="canvas">{{ chart }}</canvas>
</div>
```

So I have tried this while updating just to see where the problem is:

```
this.chart.data.labels = [10,15,22,14];
this.chart.data.datasets[0].data = [1,111,24,24];
```

After this the data are displayed normaly, no appends. It is shown like a new Chart what is actually that I need, but with the data from an API.

I am wondering why it doesn't reset chart when I use data from an API, any solutions ?

Comment: Are you entering the first part of your `if`? At first glance it seems to me you never enter it. If that's not the case could you provide a working example of your code?

Comment: At first, else statement is run. Called with getValueById(1) on init. Code works, chart is drawn, I just have that problem when for example getValueById(7) is called after init, graph append to one with value 1. I can provide images of graph if u want

Comment: At the moment I cannot provide you with a working example but here is what I would do: combine the `if` and `else` into one function specifically for updating the chart, create the chart with empty data in `OnInit` for example and call the update function there with default data. Then call the update function with different parameters whenever you want. The trick is to make sure you are using the same chart and clear it before setting the new data, I had some problems if I didn't do that.